# Moving objects in PyGame and taking a single input

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a game in PyGame where I need to pick up a plate and move it around the kitchen. so far I have managed to have the player collide and interact with the object but have not been able to pick up and move the object around the screen. I've been stuck on this issue for weeks and any help would be massively appreciated.

```
def new(self):
  self.plate = pg.sprite.Group()
  for tile_object in self.map.tmxdata.objects:
    if tile_object.name == 'plate':
            self.plate.x = tile_object.x
            self.plate.y = tile_object.y
            Plate(self, self.plate.x, self.plate.y)
```

````
      touch=False
      if (tx-32)<= x and (tx+32) >= x and (ty-64)<= y and (ty+64) >= y:
          touch = True
      elif (ty-32)<= y and (ty+32) >= y and (tx-64)<= x and (tx+64) >= x:
          touch = True
      return(touch)
 
def update(self):
      self.all_sprites.update()
      x = self.player.pos[0]
      y = self.player.pos[1]
      holding = 0
      keys_pressed = self.get_pg_events()```

      touch = self.grid_location(self.player.pos[0] ,self.player.pos[1] ,self.plate.x, self.plate.y)
      if touch == True:
          self.space_bar_plate.reposition(self.player.pos[0], self.player.pos[1]+64)
          keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
          if keys[pg.K_SPACE]:
              now = pg.time.get_ticks()
              if now - self.player.last_action > ACTION_RATE:
                  self.player.last_action = now
                  self.plate.x = math.cos(self.player.rot*math.pi/180)*80+self.player.pos[0]
                  self.plate.y = math.sin(self.player.rot*math.pi/180)*80+self.player.pos[1]
                  self.plate = Plate(self, self.plate.x , self.plate.y)
     else:
         self.space_bar_plate.reposition(-32, 0)```

in my sprites file

class Plate(pg.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, game, x, y):
      self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.plate
      pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
      self.game = game
      self.image = game.plate_img
      self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
      self.pos = (x, y)
      self.rect.center = self.pos

  def reposition(self, x, y):
      self.pos = (x, y)
      self.rect.center = self.pos
````

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example of how to do something like that. Use <kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd> to move and <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to pick up and drop the black box.

```
import pygame

RESOLUTION = 800, 600
TILESIZE = 32
PLAYER_SPEED = 200
FPS = 60

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill('dodgerblue')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(pos)
        self.movement = pygame.Vector2()
        self.item = None

    def update(self, dt, events):
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        self.movement.x, self.movement.y = 0, 0
        if pressed[pygame.K_w]: self.movement.y = -1
        if pressed[pygame.K_a]: self.movement.x = -1
        if pressed[pygame.K_s]: self.movement.y =  1
        if pressed[pygame.K_d]: self.movement.x =  1
        if self.movement.length() > 0:
            self.movement.normalize_ip()
        self.pos += self.movement * dt * PLAYER_SPEED
        self.rect.center = self.pos

        if self.item:
            self.item.pos += self.movement * dt * PLAYER_SPEED
            self.item.rect.center = self.item.pos

        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                self.pick_up() if not self.item else self.drop()

    def pick_up(self):
        collisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.groups()[0], False)
        items = list(s for s in collisions if hasattr(s, 'can_be_picked_up') and s.can_be_picked_up)
        if items:
            self.item = items[0]

    def drop(self):
        self.item = None

class Plate(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill('black')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(pos)
        self.can_be_picked_up = True

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(RESOLUTION)
    dt, clock = 0, pygame.time.Clock()
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    Player((400, 300), sprites)
    Plate((200, 200), sprites)
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
        screen.fill('grey')
        sprites.update(dt, events)
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(FPS) / 1000

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

As you can see, in the `update` function of the `Player` we check if <kbd>space</kbd> was pressed. Then we check if we're already holding an item.

If yes, we drop it.

If not, we check all sprites that we currently collide with and take that first that has `can_be_picked_up` set to `True` (you don't have to do this this way but why not) and pick it up.

Picking it up just means setting it to `self.item` and then update its position in the player's `update` method, too.

Of course, there are multiple ways to do something like this; but I think this quite similar to what you tried to do in your code.

Answer (score 0):

First you track if a click is made and change a variable to True:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    clicked = True
```

If you release the mouse you reset this variable:

```
elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
    clicked = False
```

Then again in your pygame loop you track the mouse position by:

```
elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
    if clicked:
        x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0], pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]
```

Then when you blit the image you do it with these x and y values.